# Setting upstream branch in git: branch does not exist

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-bash

I am using Git to push several branches into one already existing (including the branches) remote repo on my company's GitLab. The branches in the remote only contain a README.md. All branches have not been versioned with Git yet which is why I use the following commands to push them to their remote locations:

Git Version: 2.31.1.windows.1 (git bash)

```
cd branchx
git init -b branchx
git remote add origin git@my.company.com:project-group/repo.git

# this is the problematic line:
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branchx

git pull --allow-unrelated-histories (to pull the README.md)
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin branchx
```

This worked like a charm for my first branch. However, when I try to set the upstream branch for another branch (in another folder, where x in branchx is a number) with

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branchx
```

I get the error

```
fatal: branch 'branchx' does not exist
```

However, if I type in `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/` and double-tab, I can see the exact `origin/branchx` I am trying to set as upstream there.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you do the `git branch --set-upstream-to` *after* pushing the branch? The push request causes the other Git to *create* the branch on *its* end, which tells your Git to *create* the remote-tracking name on *your* end. Once these are all created successfully, *then* you can set the upstream.

Comment: This is why `git push` has the `-u` option: you can't set the upstream until the upstream exists, which isn't until the first push creates it. The `-u` runs the set-upstream-to for you if the push succeeds.

Comment: The other case I think you may be asking about is the special case of a totally-empty repository, or right after `git checkout --orphan`. In this case, you are on a branch that *does not yet exist*. The branch gets created by the first `git commit` operation. Only once the branch exists can you set its upstream.

Comment: I am confused then. The branches already exist in the remote because they have been manually added with the "create branch" functionality in GitLab, but I still need to `push -u` first?

Comment: Ah, no, if you have an existing branch in the remote, you just have to first have your local Git *call up* the remote, so that your Git can *see* their branch, and create your own local `origin/<branch>`. Then it exists locally so that you can set an upstream locally. (I.e., you need to run `git fetch`.)

Comment: Since I need to pull and remove a README.md first anyways, I just moved the pull statement up in the list, doing exactly what you said in your last comment. The order is now init, remote add, pull --allow-unrelated-histories, rm (for the Readme), add, commit and push -u. Just for people stumbling upon this via Google. Thank you!